# Applying custom function across groups using dplyr and ggplot using facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data which looks something like the following:

```
# A time tibble: 6 x 3
# Index: index
      ID index      value
   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1 276217 2001-01-01  1.42
2 276217 2001-01-08  1.14
3 276217 2001-01-15  1.35
4 276217 2001-01-22  1.30
5 276217 2001-01-29  1.33
6 276217 2001-02-05  1.11
```

I have 2 groups and for each group I am trying to apply a function and plot a graph using `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`.

I have the following function:

```
tidy_acf <- function(data, value, lags = 0:20) {

  value_expr <- enquo(value)

  acf_values <- data %>%
    pull(value) %>%
    acf(lag.max = tail(lags, 1), plot = FALSE) %>%
    .$acf %>%
    .[,,1]

  ret <- tibble(acf = acf_values) %>%
    rowid_to_column(var = "lag") %>%
    mutate(lag = lag - 1) %>%
    filter(lag %in% lags)

  return(ret)
}

max_lag <- 52 * 12
```

Then I am trying to apply the following:

```
  DATA %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  tidy_acf(value, lags = 0:max_lag) %>%
  ggplot(aes(lag, acf)) +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(ID))
```

So I am expecting a grid of 2 plots.

The error I have is:

```
Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `ID`.
* Plot is missing `ID`
* Layer 1 is missing `ID`
* Layer 2 is missing `ID`
* Layer 3 is missing `ID`
```

The `ACF` function I think "ignores" the `group_by` command and calculates the ACF for all the data. I have tried using `mutate` and `do` without much luck.

Also when `ggplot` tries to read the line `facet_grid(rows = vars(ID))` there is no `ID` variable.

DATA:

```
structure(list(ID = c(276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 
276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 276217, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 673535, 
673535, 673535, 673535), index = structure(c(11323, 11330, 11337, 
11344, 11351, 11358, 11365, 11372, 11379, 11386, 11393, 11400, 
11407, 11414, 11421, 11435, 11442, 11449, 11456, 11463, 11470, 
11477, 11484, 11491, 11498, 11505, 11512, 11519, 11526, 11533, 
11540, 11547, 11554, 11561, 11568, 11575, 11582, 11589, 11596, 
11603, 11610, 11617, 11624, 11631, 11638, 11645, 11652, 11659, 
11666, 11673, 11680, 11687, 11694, 11701, 11708, 11715, 11722, 
11729, 11736, 11743, 11750, 11757, 11764, 11771, 11778, 11785, 
11792, 11799, 11806, 11813, 11820, 11827, 11834, 11841, 11848, 
11855, 11862, 11869, 11876, 11883, 11890, 11897, 11904, 11911, 
11918, 11925, 11932, 11939, 11946, 11953, 11960, 11967, 11974, 
11981, 11988, 11995, 12002, 12009, 12016, 12023, 12030, 12037, 
12044, 12051, 12058, 12065, 12072, 12079, 12086, 12093, 12100, 
12107, 12114, 12121, 12128, 12135, 12142, 12149, 12156, 12163, 
12170, 12177, 12184, 12191, 12198, 12205, 12212, 12219, 12226, 
12233, 12240, 12247, 12254, 12261, 12268, 12275, 12282, 12289, 
12296, 12303, 12310, 12317, 12324, 12331, 12338, 12345, 12352, 
12359, 12366, 12373, 12380, 12387, 12394, 12401, 12408, 12415, 
12422, 12429, 12436, 12443, 12450, 12457, 12464, 12471, 12478, 
12485, 12492, 12499, 12506, 12513, 12520, 12527, 12534, 12541, 
12548, 12555, 12562, 12569, 12576, 12583, 12590, 12597, 12604, 
12611, 12618, 12625, 12632, 12639, 12646, 12653, 12660, 12667, 
12674, 12681, 12688, 12695, 12702, 12709, 12716, 12723, 12730, 
12737, 12744, 12751, 12758, 12765, 12772, 12779, 12786, 12793, 
12800, 12807, 12814, 12821, 12828, 12835, 12842, 12849, 12856, 
12863, 12870, 12877, 12884, 12891, 12898, 12905, 12912, 12919, 
12926, 12933, 12940, 12947, 12954, 12961, 12968, 12975, 12982, 
12989, 12996, 13003, 13010, 13017, 13024, 13031, 13038, 13045, 
13052, 13059, 13066, 13073, 13080, 13087, 13094, 13101, 13108, 
13115, 13122, 13129, 13136, 13143, 11323, 11330, 11337, 11344, 
11351, 11358, 11365, 11372, 11379, 11386, 11393, 11400, 11407, 
11414, 11421, 11435, 11442, 11449, 11456, 11463, 11470, 11477, 
11484, 11491, 11498, 11505, 11512, 11519, 11526, 11533, 11540, 
11547, 11554, 11561, 11568, 11575, 11582, 11589, 11596, 11603, 
11610, 11617, 11624, 11631, 11638, 11645, 11652, 11659, 11666, 
11673, 11680, 11687, 11694, 11701, 11708, 11715, 11722, 11729, 
11736, 11743, 11750, 11757, 11764, 11771, 11778, 11785, 11792, 
11799, 11806, 11813, 11820, 11827, 11834, 11841, 11848, 11855, 
11862, 11869, 11876, 11883, 11890, 11897, 11904, 11911, 11918, 
11925, 11932, 11939, 11946, 11953, 11960, 11967, 11974, 11981, 
11988, 11995, 12002, 12009, 12016, 12023, 12030, 12037, 12044, 
12051, 12058, 12065, 12072, 12079, 12086, 12093, 12100, 12107, 
12114, 12121, 12128, 12135, 12142, 12149, 12156, 12163, 12170, 
12177, 12184, 12191, 12198, 12205, 12212, 12219, 12226, 12233, 
12240, 12247, 12254, 12261, 12268, 12275, 12282, 12289, 12296, 
12303, 12310, 12317, 12324, 12331, 12338, 12345, 12352, 12359, 
12366, 12373, 12380, 12387, 12394, 12401, 12408, 12415, 12422, 
12429, 12436, 12443, 12450, 12457, 12464, 12471, 12478, 12485, 
12492, 12499, 12506, 12513, 12520, 12527, 12534, 12541, 12548, 
12555, 12562, 12569, 12576, 12583, 12590, 12597, 12604, 12611, 
12618, 12625, 12632, 12639, 12646, 12653, 12660, 12667, 12674, 
12681, 12688, 12695, 12702, 12709, 12716, 12723, 12730, 12737, 
12744, 12751, 12758, 12765, 12772, 12779, 12786, 12793, 12800, 
12807, 12814, 12821, 12828, 12835, 12842, 12849, 12856, 12863, 
12870, 12877, 12884, 12891, 12898, 12905, 12912, 12919, 12926, 
12933, 12940, 12947, 12954, 12961, 12968, 12975, 12982, 12989, 
12996, 13003, 13010, 13017, 13024, 13031, 13038, 13045, 13052, 
13059, 13066, 13073, 13080, 13087, 13094, 13101, 13108, 13115, 
13122, 13129, 13136, 13143), class = "Date"), value = c(1.41937020560682, 
1.13730371661759, 1.3539311150167, 1.29696778568529, 1.3323626647449, 
1.10981390720746, 1.18071375602539, 1.19207097496899, 1.19676816234154, 
1.22239101776685, 1.2506070891073, 1.41996279851121, 1.12626118927859, 
1.35762335181086, 1.39713439429607, 1.38612414908988, 1.34648704163679, 
1.30960297429645, 1.32473144759308, 1.41881033664487, 1.42977103998914, 
1.45886017825442, 1.43168869907128, 1.37756572500706, 1.68909064430956, 
1.5361228794478, 1.48611232259234, 1.58072013349794, 1.45481742038903, 
1.4817092550674, 1.24105214048689, 1.41069885959673, 1.28674202240156, 
1.54781553519693, 1.38282364059626, 1.42928968301089, 1.17276730477843, 
1.34700737129064, 1.13164253306323, 1.42389865505797, 1.17592348061104, 
1.38300636631992, 1.3547327097731, 1.28131014670212, 1.2555870634607, 
1.52185998250405, 1.17456066715388, 1.23671084290859, 1.35047806931946, 
1.49865878240371, 1.65716461782272, 1.43726769110404, 1.31690661185925, 
1.29129879112465, 1.19842719818708, 1.29484342347787, 1.52377764218684, 
1.12200241957802, 1.20079971092347, 1.16407218274476, 1.34362475426389, 
1.32208564023239, 1.25706881626001, 1.29752528762653, 1.25449120532999, 
1.19172390630137, 1.31170344960018, 1.24839862907423, 1.21805675875317, 
1.12246668431943, 1.21680442566904, 1.233324635472, 1.3183740810356, 
1.34191361856964, 1.27794948142411, 1.2350002695076, 1.40188172678391, 
1.3905788567514, 1.52842869568866, 1.34555771095665, 1.47268660991843, 
1.46644830848524, 1.32154683578951, 1.24416519323, 1.21297851393759, 
1.33453445324598, 1.39167121745469, 1.47121045110368, 1.28918946132591, 
1.27498741795507, 1.31327037340205, 1.27139947787948, 1.30133531812561, 
1.45850847546917, 1.31951867476118, 1.04465952644041, 1.26616814025568, 
1.45491572126488, 1.49066211565058, 1.21260446801099, 1.51101227343164, 
1.28374730661533, 1.4606510930363, 1.54310674593129, 1.3943023792947, 
1.21617488502602, 1.27779510696235, 1.26492049349337, 1.28893561379684, 
1.34101339160729, 1.23653444605546, 1.52937951802558, 1.24611066742983, 
1.40556767894264, 1.36613239155494, 1.15566891632031, 1.36978139561172, 
1.21620591005457, 1.19672278171019, 1.31878337610884, 1.23841209401771, 
1.34868610368419, 1.18860731906096, 1.43455676790059, 1.28875013956958, 
1.27312347874578, 1.29363479109929, 1.33262043145855, 1.38160602058133, 
1.61479387947761, 1.35804447140576, 1.41149040095419, 1.48017031490425, 
1.47576645263688, 1.5245822496389, 1.33559282862022, 1.2599120663954, 
1.35966779424493, 1.2266712872336, 1.33798458662942, 1.20584978864545, 
1.18799246468728, 1.18385487480062, 1.0622352775507, 1.10529104509327, 
1.35359695992605, 1.12279116483699, 1.03213829824401, 1.08654744699064, 
1.26657156230531, 1.40230470980855, 1.02834232411836, 1.40946282039393, 
1.28539537543728, 1.43892218365149, 1.49298397663843, 1.15976118620392, 
1.20804939370669, 1.10072248466824, 1.14422045115725, 1.2028133706493, 
1.11274509334125, 1.21394374577131, 1.12952599532327, 1.10682691857272, 
1.22839520113321, 1.30304178253435, 1.18115210023735, 1.21616506619252, 
1.1486616532461, 1.06528565526184, 1.28015893048186, 1.04568291345179, 
1.19030647756617, 1.17271787931786, 1.24257225165359, 1.28837051097269, 
1.21364584611854, 1.32183965388118, 1.62565762633464, 1.34108886133387, 
1.45861718634725, 1.40680343219648, 1.49898988719805, 1.37365484263548, 
1.40194709465205, 1.52119768777043, 1.1546139113979, 1.34663756991197, 
1.19175504361163, 1.38802433610545, 1.42482301211201, 1.28861676565775, 
1.29583234931414, 1.3539253596777, 1.19371894069907, 1.29596409461602, 
1.31604466739086, 1.16953727329986, 1.24571329130068, 1.20977722712303, 
1.32133145369149, 1.22022262451546, 1.11043339713881, 1.18314381744431, 
1.26442168060822, 1.20687048368665, 1.19001235469596, 1.13379603549586, 
1.15500524682456, 1.29730166142161, 1.42125202522948, 1.30979026623885, 
1.19822081427195, 0.970223979901651, 1.01170895674301, 1.06833234437818, 
1.1567954374083, 1.14600483321563, 1.28862549400355, 1.26172237771525, 
1.02111868419395, 1.07703997971764, 1.16778050692621, 1.23274164934758, 
1.14220017603011, 1.26895607326201, 1.13052624629828, 1.15093653420372, 
1.21421061979431, 1.31260087277151, 1.23609359665254, 1.22091083541942, 
1.18755107607541, 1.20276269855061, 1.15596099825208, 1.29433716711344, 
1.34000352773031, 1.374339559464, 1.3320530338296, 1.38213986834908, 
1.09417814672424, 1.41175179189304, 1.4443513919479, 1.18686762085048, 
1.12443328747865, 1.29014597840925, 1.25944166196376, 1.11314610197784, 
1.12316114098931, 1.08278643471745, 1.08446914721635, 1.07284297889302, 
1.26479980128396, 1.22784784783676, 1.16565880517992, 1.1331496618174, 
1.14958582045566, 1.42505611714813, 1.36497139656022, 0.762877732531809, 
0.5894904370784, 0.52640374646506, 0.760587540343175, 0.857893882608007, 
0.782581957325627, 0.642950696238089, 0.773040192810864, 0.692955963984261, 
0.608798647608425, 0.719257304351197, 1.09157551261522, 0.605847308747244, 
0.607101755350968, 0.931947730208544, 0.623059079872713, 0.652200825716763, 
0.783988475111917, 0.708693777149976, 0.851179407205504, 0.867212188981653, 
1.01249123310826, 0.832261335348492, 1.01642068444198, 0.768581853602418, 
0.738178550284871, 1.07087389090617, 0.725185530890722, 0.915022447538265, 
1.03656372445932, 0.683513589539164, 0.760759035493538, 0.962607981940909, 
0.881106061148774, 1.07992272712261, 0.6940197513087, 1.24427844954137, 
0.937092846348055, 0.785797045379898, 1.09913118425944, 0.984160545246009, 
0.769094802245811, 0.892485889935335, 0.762981553768869, 0.962905698297224, 
0.910723959387533, 0.796823913083302, 1.11776176611975, 0.990528711597118, 
0.916277885817988, 0.754922846376312, 0.789859817063917, 0.583252537946175, 
0.869048949001103, 0.904241238082762, 0.792797391202002, 0.824905104850026, 
0.796067287268244, 0.705002929794062, 0.610738122940513, 0.740039977653799, 
0.610202923126631, 0.730617879642999, 0.818060623496325, 0.686573473815161, 
0.705818060545842, 0.7344556153191, 0.621681577668493, 1.01291062465701, 
0.726797765613636, 0.799983190290583, 0.81352068284914, 1.20290672862058, 
0.956972752784302, 0.899695591941931, 0.734494760133977, 0.918082644120655, 
0.803144251887721, 0.90840105184199, 1.01870315081598, 0.754963006088199, 
0.655924111314657, 0.635979000600382, 0.637823081118935, 0.74219078811824, 
0.658443679394198, 0.848643856810564, 1.01679807837156, 0.64924000203248, 
0.721495807650437, 0.995843616253178, 0.587567067234205, 0.885388384396393, 
0.804755702236206, 0.88039649895026, 1.22892254775891, 0.654383489887676, 
0.684414353519528, 0.82311483323441, 0.738445568441471, 0.985270508555264, 
0.538027793838735, 0.67254042415109, 0.633305896313126, 0.677514338408576, 
0.707861122799185, 0.898879947396628, 0.568007850104993, 0.820356325826786, 
0.890132617561718, 0.819518861020891, 0.640866340833552, 0.740566063515691, 
0.645941423240264, 0.640005312025865, 0.512662089777166, 0.545981143731435, 
0.645783228140564, 0.650566996249936, 0.932063079996881, 0.8297715985113, 
0.583812645526694, 0.79671714309694, 0.554608909530225, 0.772774431644987, 
0.612018242382329, 0.632731183161737, 1.10874043293385, 0.691113408480122, 
0.67670539385424, 0.756826654641211, 0.768060859016454, 0.885031727269359, 
0.823484255503393, 0.73517482053536, 1.03739291336419, 0.870623096705543, 
1.1194311197314, 0.726119289744962, 0.644851629240191, 0.76013331519735, 
0.560668740229276, 0.931616505672441, 0.762174394414433, 0.607422071693735, 
0.794972372981508, 0.853881172459784, 0.843633537139329, 1.05041450556316, 
0.536434294372646, 0.656612696998115, 0.558405219921965, 0.755700609928556, 
0.671622788195764, 0.773200131224459, 0.787809813915869, 0.752185735418751, 
0.66574833782471, 0.745533410847401, 0.812030376024714, 0.856602413966287, 
0.791251263099112, 0.792360401499752, 0.544983809039963, 0.677788404933327, 
0.811903043853608, 0.794753307517171, 0.723075319600815, 0.562075181459737, 
0.678502428959742, 0.77053008135789, 1.14362850092319, 0.741834489079122, 
0.546785233571552, 0.795344208194642, 0.505119229967037, 0.920730172911113, 
0.796735200185373, 0.75490879746383, 0.766143669886884, 0.858382127622966, 
0.741361275131017, 0.958796686496966, 0.730874542052134, 0.743581487352913, 
0.794645828336577, 0.827064450971909, 0.535165553807624, 0.79714773022668, 
0.933647930767804, 0.904781872982919, 0.778038374261388, 0.737032233790766, 
0.636467007427987, 0.588315531583391, 0.57789678487892, 0.653445424930302, 
0.716818765540808, 0.681654384075588, 0.941300215713349, 0.816145818070346, 
0.653499164576688, 0.65366241688387, 0.635082148614803, 0.782506231125364, 
0.540581221109251, 0.880390955968106, 0.949533548689565, 0.656740433162245, 
0.645784296818701, 0.835744907749697, 0.883383077894964, 0.856871617610107, 
0.793507512069987, 0.644649833901959, 0.667659239793578, 0.566975791202607, 
0.805072718065176, 0.76189782781533, 0.908993183134203, 0.57958180848488, 
0.595493495671665, 0.595298981005907, 0.691244844002269, 0.559001941268423, 
0.841944908413524, 0.502638437519587, 0.995560002118792, 1.03400866336882, 
0.781447555328994, 0.848505938905025, 1.10657203868824, 1.00949522054762, 
0.680172374435646, 0.980497319076417, 0.640836501543487, 1.03473567233595, 
0.970381583577073, 1.15687939463795, 0.775243943082199, 0.75378979506369, 
0.636035597193233, 0.691945202550093, 0.712384411483125, 0.780216998875879, 
0.465494109331028, 0.683261414179953, 0.791400883275817, 0.555590485062775, 
0.536696577165946, 0.413733248705531, 0.691415618521668, 0.65952361324002, 
0.562421063932012, 0.810094133287698, 0.601494620395893, 0.43699550503586, 
0.679366721960758, 0.518055035225684, 0.663463830695837)), row.names = c(NA, 
-520L), index_quo = ~index, index_time_zone = "UTC", class = c("tbl_time", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `split` and `map` instead of `group_by`

```
DATA %>% 
  split(.$ID) %>% 
  map(~tidy_acf(.,value, lags = 0:max_lag)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(lag, acf)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       facet_grid(rows = vars(ID))
```

Your function can be optimised like this

```
tidy_acf_fix <- function(data, value, lags = 0:20) {
      value_expr <- enquo(value)

     acf_values <- data %>%
      pull(!!value_expr) %>%
      acf(lag.max = tail(lags, 1), plot = FALSE) %>%
      broom::tidy()
 }
```

Or without any function

```
DATA %>%
  split(.$ID) %>%
  map(~with(.,acf(value, lag.max =max_lag, plot = FALSE)) %>% 
        broom::tidy()) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lag, acf)) +
   geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(rows = vars(ID))
```

Comment: Would you be able to add some comments to the ACF function and talk me through your optimised version? The ACF function I provided is not mine so I would like to know exactly whats happening under the hood.

Comment: I can't as I'm also not familiar with it. But try it in "standalone mode". Furthermore I don't understand why you want to use a complicated function since is it also working without any. See my edits for that.

Comment: Thanks anyways for the solution. The original author states "`However, we’d like to get the ACF values as data so we can investigate the underlying data. To do so, we’ll create a custom function, tidy_acf()`" Link to tutorial: https://www.r-bloggers.com/time-series-deep-learning-forecasting-sunspots-with-keras-stateful-lstm-in-r/